# using jquery and Math.random to have dynamically generated <span>s animate at different times

Tags: jquery, animation, dynamic

I am trying to create a paper falling effect, and I am trying to have each of my `<span>`s begin their animation at a different time using a `Math.random` number. I have tried a few things, but here is the last thing I've tried before coming here... Does anyone have an idea of how to do this ?

```
var maxBills = 100; //max amount per page

//generate random number

for (var i = 0; i < maxBills ; i ++){

    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*1500);

    var randomPosition = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);

    var bills = $("<span>")
                    .addClass('billsBillsBills')
                    .text('paper')
                    .css({
                        left : randomNumber,
                    })

    //have each bill start falling at a different time

    var fall = $(bills).css('-webkit-animation-duration', randomNumber );

        $('body').append(bills);



}
```

Comment: You should post a JSbin example that includes the surrounding CSS and any relevant HTML markup :)

Comment: If you want the animations to start at different times then you probably want to randomize `animation-delay` rather than `animation-duration`. Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-delay

Comment: PS. This might be a nice use-case for requestAnimationFrame (pure JS animations) rather than CSS. In my opinion, that approach is more readable than a mixture of JS (for randomization) and CSS (for animation). But that's totally your call. :)

Comment: What isn't working exactly? Did you mean `left: randomPosition` in your css adjustment?

Comment: Also, if you want their movements to be different from each other, you need to loop over `bills`.

Comment: Like maybe [this](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/dLcdak12/)?

Comment: @AustinMullins the 'falling at different times' isn't working, and I think you are right, I need to loop through my bills in order to have them start at different time...any idea how to do this? My code below isn't the answer....

Thanks!

for( var i; i< bills; i++){
...
}

Comment: @AustinMullins oops just saw your previous response. That's exactly the effect I am looking for. Just have to check out your code to see how you created that magic! Thanks a bunch for helping a newbie out. :)

Comment: I can add a proper answer with an explanation in a while. I just wanted to make sure I understood the intent first.

Comment: @AustinMullins I tried to break it down to see why you did certain things, a lot of it made sense, but an explanation would be awesome. :)

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code I posted on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/dLcdak12/) with some additional notes to explain what's going on.

```
var maxBills = 10; // Start with a reasonable number of objects

// We need to set the height of the container. I've never found
// (or at least can never remember) a way to do this in pure CSS.
$(document.body).css({height: window.innerHeight});

// I'm naming the animation function twice here, which is not
// technically necessary. If I were worried about debugging, having a
// name after the function keyword would help.
// Also, I'm naming the parameter $e to indicate that I expect a jQuery
// element object.
var randBill = function randBill($e) {
    // randomNumber: the random duration of the animation from 0 to 1.5 seconds
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*1500);

    // randomPosition: the random new "left" value, in %.
    //   This is set up to range from 25% to 75%
    var randomPosition = Math.floor(Math.random()*50) + 25;

    // Since you described wanting a "falling paper" animation, I decided
    // to add a random fall value as well. This ranges from -5 (actually
    // rising 5 pixels) to 45 pixels down.
    var randomFall = Math.floor(Math.random()*50) - 5;

    // Grab essential metrics as integers:
    //     For these values, jQuery actually kind of gets in the way.
    //     At the end I'll link to a pure HTML5 canvas implementation
    //     that is much more computationally efficient.
    var parentHeight = parseInt($e.parent().css("height"));
    var billTop = parseInt($e.css("top"));

    // The first time through, $e.css("top") returns undefined.
    if (isNaN(billTop)) billTop = 0;
    var billHeight = parseInt($e.css("height"));

    // This line checks to see if we've already reached the bottom of the
    // container. If so, we don't want to move past it.
    var newTop = Math.min(parentHeight - billHeight, billTop + randomFall);

    // Here we use jQuery's animate function to change the position and
    // make sure this function gets called again when the animation is done.
    $e.animate(
        {left: randomPosition + "%", top:newTop + "px"}, // The target values
        randomNumber, // The duration of the animation
        "swing", // The "easing" function. This is the default.
                 // It causes realistic acceleration / deceleration.
        function() { // This is the function that will be called when the
                     // current animation is complete.

          // We're done if we reached the bottom
          if (newTop < parentHeight - billHeight) {
            randBill($e); // Just call this function again 
          }
    });
};

// This is essentially a constructor for a "Bill" object
var makeBill = function() {
                var bill = $("<span>")
                    .addClass('billsBillsBills')
                    .text('paper');
                return bill;
};

// Make an array of bills with the size specified up top
var bills = [];
for(var i = 0; i < maxBills; i++) {
    bills.push(makeBill());
}

// Add the bills to the DOM
$('body').append(bills);

// Not every browser has Array.map yet, but they should! This function will
// be called once on each element of the array. It's important that I call
// this function after the elements have been added to the DOM so that
// el.parent() actually returns the container object.
bills.map(function(el) { randBill(el); });
```

Since we really don't care about user interactions with the individual "bills", we don't actually need DOM elements, so a pure HTML5 canvas implementation should be more efficient. I didn't notice any performance issues with the jQuery version myself, but I like the canvas version better in theory. See a demo of it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/kadekb8q/2/). The thing I don't like about my canvas version is that I haven't implemented an easing function like jQuery's "swing", so the bills move in a somewhat jarring zig-zag rather than a smooth flutter.

Comment: I made a [WebGL version](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/9m4c2ssx/1/) too. It takes a lot just to set up a context, but once you've got it, you just need to update the vertices every frame and GL can handle the rest, plus you could apply all kinds of effects in shaders. Also, the simulation has to take place in (-1.0, 1.0) space instead of pixelspace. It takes a while to get used to that.